# Interact with Minecraft Server

Tags: server, services, minecraft

I have a Minecraft sever running that gets started automatically using the init.d scripts.  Now I want to be able to give myself admin privileges but I need to send commands to the server.  How can I do that without stopping it and running it manually?

Comment: so, you want the server running as your user?  Just do "sudo -u USER COMMAND" in the init script

Comment: Not exactly.  I set up a user called minecraft and that's who the script runs as.  But the script is running now and I want to be able to interact with it.  How can I send commands to the process while it's running?

Comment: I'm not sure how the minecraft server works, but if you start it using "screen" then you could connect to it by doing "sudo -u minecraft screen -r"

Comment: I get this message `Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' - please check.`  Even if I su to minecraft and try to screen -r

Comment: It's running on a remote server that I ssh into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just calling `sudo /etc/init.d/minecraft stop` then starting the server `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui` and opping my player and starting it again with `sudo /etc/init.d/minecraft start`

Answer (score 2):

When you ssh, you need to pass a -t option to allow screen to work.  Or you could add your username to the ops.txt file.

But, what you really want is a full-featured bells-and-whistles script that uses screen to interact with the Minecraft server.  Check out [Minecraft Sheller.](https://github.com/endofzero/Minecraft-Sheller)  I think it provides what you want and more.

Answer (score 2):

If you get

```
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' - please check.
```

use

```
sudo -u minecraft
script '/dev/null'
screen -r
```